# Why do Pandas integer `dtypes` not behave the same on Unix and Windows?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

In checking the `dtypes` for columns in a Pandas `DataFrame`, I realized that the data type for an integer column is `np.int64`, but what is surprising is that on Unix this equates to `int` but on Windows it is not.  Why do they not behave the same?  Is there a way to create the DataFrame in a way that the result is the same when compared using `df.dtypes == int`?

Here is some sample code to illustrate.

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: pd.__version__
Out[3]: '1.0.1'

In [4]: np.__version__
Out[4]: '1.18.1'

In [5]: data = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': range(5), 'col_2': np.linspace(0, 1, 5)})

In [6]: data.dtypes
Out[6]: 
col_1      int64
col_2    float64
dtype: object

In [7]: data.dtypes == float
Out[7]: 
col_1    False
col_2     True
dtype: bool
```

All of that produces the same result on Windows and Unix, but if I compare the dtypes to `int` on Windows I get

```
In [8]: data.dtypes == int
Out[8]: 
col_1    False
col_2    False
dtype: bool
```

and on Unix I get

```
In [8]: data.dtypes == int
Out[8]:
col_1     True
col_2    False
dtype: bool
```

I tried specifying the datatypes.  This works on Unix, I can input the datatypes by adding `dtype=(int, float)`

```
In [9]: data = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': range(5), 'col_2': np.linspace(0, 1, 5)}, dtype=(int, float))

In [10]: data.dtypes
Out[10]:
col_1      int64
col_2    float64
dtype: object
```

but on Windows this code fails with a `ValueError`

```
In [10]: data = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': range(5), 'col_2': np.linspace(0, 1, 5)}, dtype=(int, float))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-284f0f12d3b6> in <module>
----> 1 data = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': range(5), 'col_2': np.linspace(0, 1, 5)}, dtype=(int, float))

~\Miniconda3\envs\pandas_test\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    423             data = {}
    424         if dtype is not None:
--> 425             dtype = self._validate_dtype(dtype)
    426
    427         if isinstance(data, DataFrame):

~\Miniconda3\envs\pandas_test\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _validate_dtype(self, dtype)
    257
    258         if dtype is not None:
--> 259             dtype = pandas_dtype(dtype)
    260
    261             # a compound dtype

~\Miniconda3\envs\pandas_test\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\common.py in pandas_dtype(dtype)
   1872     # raise a consistent TypeError if failed
   1873     try:
-> 1874         npdtype = np.dtype(dtype)
   1875     except SyntaxError:
   1876         # np.dtype uses `eval` which can raise SyntaxError

ValueError: mismatch in size of old and new data-descriptor
```

Comment: Yes, it's expected but unfortunate. You should make your `dtype`s cross-platform by specifying the size explicitly - i.e., by using `np.int32`, `np.int64`, etc.

Comment: Is that a 32 vs 64 bit Python thing? Instead of Win vs Linux.

Comment: "on Unix this equates to int but on Windows it is equal to int" - uh, what?

Comment: The way equality is defined for `numpy.dtype` objects is a mess. Just don't rely on it. I'd be explicit and check for precisely the types you are looking for, and not rely on already ill-defined equality between objects that have no business being equal `numpy.dtype` objects and python `type` objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a platform agnostic means of comparing any type of integer or float, you can use

```py
In [10]: [np.issubdtype(dtype, np.integer) for dtype in data.dtypes]
Out[10]: [True, False]

In [11]: [np.issubdtype(dtype, np.float) for dtype in data.dtypes]
Out[11]: [False, True]
```

---

The primary issue behind the Windows/Unix difference is that `int` equates to a pandas `dtype` of `np.int64` on Unix and `np.int32` on Windows.

This code illustrates the difference in behavior:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

print(f'numpy version: {np.__version__}')
print(f'pandas version: {pd.__version__}')

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'col_i': range(5),
    'col_f': np.linspace(0, 1, 5),
})
data['col_i32'] = data.col_i.astype(np.int32)
data['col_i64'] = data.col_i.astype(np.int64)
data['col_f32'] = data.col_i.astype(np.float32)
data['col_f64'] = data.col_i.astype(np.float64)
print(f'\ndata.dtypes: \n{data.dtypes}')
print(f'\ndata.dtypes == int: \n{data.dtypes == int}')
print(f'\ndata.dtypes == float: \n{data.dtypes == float}')
```

Here is the result on Windows:

```py
numpy version: 1.18.1
pandas version: 1.0.1

data.dtypes:
col_i        int64
col_f      float64
col_i32      int32
col_i64      int64
col_f32    float32
col_f64    float64
dtype: object

data.dtypes == int:
col_i      False
col_f      False
col_i32     True  # the np.int32 column
col_i64    False
col_f32    False
col_f64    False
dtype: bool

data.dtypes == float:
col_i      False
col_f       True
col_i32    False
col_i64    False
col_f32    False
col_f64     True
dtype: bool
```

Here is the output on Unix:

```py
numpy version: 1.18.1
pandas version: 1.0.1

data.dtypes:
col_i        int64
col_f      float64
col_i32      int32
col_i64      int64
col_f32    float32
col_f64    float64
dtype: object

data.dtypes == int:
col_i       True  # a np.int64 column
col_f      False
col_i32    False
col_i64     True  # a np.int64 column
col_f32    False
col_f64    False
dtype: bool

data.dtypes == float:
col_i      False
col_f       True
col_i32    False
col_i64    False
col_f32    False
col_f64     True
dtype: bool
```

---

Note that the reason specifying the `dtype` fails on Windows is because the types must have the same memory size.  The [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) states that "Only a single dtype is allowed." but this is clearly not the case because either of the following work on Windows and Unix.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'col_i32': range(5), 'col_f32': np.linspace(0, 1, 5)}, dtype=(np.int32, np.float32))
```

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'col_i32': range(5), 'col_f32': np.linspace(0, 1, 5)}, dtype=(np.int64, np.float64))
```

I think what  they actually meant is "Only a singe [data size] is allowed".

The issue for the error when specifying `dtype=(int, float)` goes back to the primary issues illustrated above, where Windows is casting `int` as `np.int32` and `float` as `np.float64`, while Unix instead casts `int` as `np.int64` and `float` as `np.float64`.  Pandas requires they have the same memory size, which works out on Unix but not on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

[pandas.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) has a `dtype` parameter.

```
pandas.DataFrame(data=None, index=None, columns=None, dtype=None, copy=False)
```

You should be able to set a specific data type using that parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> np.int64 == int
False
>>> np.int32 == int
False
>>> np.int == int
True
>>> np.int == np.int64
False
>>> np.int == np.int32
False
```

It is expected and I would stick with defining what the dtype you are using by specifying int64 or int32